# Why the NuGet packages can't be installed?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

Windows 7 SP1 x64, Visual Studio 2017

I create a new *ASP.NET Core MVC* project on the base of *Empty* template:

[image]

Later I try to install the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools` and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc` packages through *NuGet Package Manager* but they throws exception during installation and are rolled back:

[image]

How can I fix it?

**UPD**

If try to do the same through NuGet Console then I see more detailed exception info:

[image]

**UPD2**

Thanks to [Leo-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7460777/leo-msft). His advice helped to me to install of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc` package but I have the problem with installing the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools` package still:

[image]

Comment: what does it say in the "output" window? there should be a "Show output from:" selector, one of which is "Package Manager". Alternatively, if you use the "Package Manager Console" and `install-pacakge Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools`, you might see the output there

Comment: @MarcGravell, I added the *UPD* section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the NuGet packages can't be installed?

That is because Package Microsoft.Composition 1.0.27 is **not compatible** with netcoreapp1.0/1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.Composition 1.0.27 supports: portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81. You will get this messages in the Output window.

To resolve this issue, you can use Visual Studio 2015 instead, if you still want to use Visual Studio 2017, you could add `PackageTargetFallback` to .csproj file like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-win+net45+wp8+win81+wpa8</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Then add those two packages by NuGet.

**Update:**

For the UPD2 question:
You can install the package `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools` by **NuGet Package Manager UI** rather than NuGet package Console. Because nuget team punted the work to support tools installs via the UI with the idea that tools will be installed by default with new projects or you can add the below lines manually to the csproj file in order to install the tool:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

For more detail information, you can refer to the [issue 4190](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4190).

Comment: Thank you. It helped to me to install the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc` package but I have the problem with installing the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools` package still. Look my *UPD2*, please

Comment: @AndreyBushman, I have updated my answer for your UPD2, please check if it works fine for you.